# What are best practices for login and passwords when there is only one user?

Tags: sql, authentication, web-applications, passwords

I feel like there's a lot of information for developers on protecting user information when there are multiple users who each need to have their passwords stored. But what if there is only 1 user? A sign up page wouldn't be needed as you could set the username and password yourself.

I'm basically making a nicer view for database stuff that is easier to get information from for someone who doesn't know SQL. But where do I store the username and password? I am using Node and I know you can use bcrypt but surely that's only useful if you're storing different user's passwords into the db and hashing them when you save it into the db.

So how do I store the information securely? Does it not matter?
Shall I just store it in the database and pull it when comparing to the password? Can I save it in the app.js file? Would be really helpful to know.

Comment: The answer would depend on the data you are trying to protect, and who is supposed to have access to it. If you only have 1 user, I'm guessing this is a website that only _you_ would have access to? How sensitive is the data you are storing? As usual with these matters, it is always a good idea to use a framework which is well tested and well maintained rather than try to redo everything from scratch yourself.

Comment: It would just be visitor information. So the most sensitive piece of data would be the visitors' number plate. So two reception staff would be the only users of it. And they wouldn't both be using it at the same time. It's just one thing to log visitors in and view information on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you only have 2 reception staff accessing this website, I think the simplest solution for you would be to use Basic Authentication. It does not require you to create a database, or handle user accounts in a database. You can read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

If your site runs on Apache, its super easy to setup using a `.htaccess` and a `.htpasswd`. As usual, make sure your site is https, otherwise the credentials will be sent in cleartext.

If the sensitivity of the data changes, or if the power associated with this account changes you should revise this authentication method accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can store username & password in database with encryption and another way is you just add credential in code itself. But if you store it in database then later on you can change but in code you can't change it from outside.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example and a description of how it works? E.g. I am looking at MD5, so when inserting the user and password value, if I do select * from users it will return the table info with the password hashed e.g. 1h31ihufou23q3, but can I check the password with the original password when logging in or do I need to use that hash?

Comment: Yes, after entering the password you need to hash it again and then after you can check in database, without hash you will not get the correct row.